# A workable strategy for a slightly complex info slider using alpinejs

Tags: alpine.js

I am still pretty new to alpine.js and coming from jQuery world, so I am still trying to get my head around it. I would like some help/insight in how to use alpine.js to create an info slider that looks like this.

```
<div id="slider"  x-data="infoSlider()">
        <!-- main image -->
        <div id="left-div" style="background-image: url('main_image.jpg'; ?>');">

            <ul>
                <li @click="toggle($event)">
                    Item 1                    
                    <div class="w-full" ></div>
                </li>
                <li @click="toggle($event)">
                    Item 2                    
                    <div ></div>
                </li>
                <li @click="toggle($event)">
                    Item 3                    
                    <div ></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- info -->
        <div id="right-div">
            <div class="info-slides w-3/5 mx-auto mt-20">
                <div class="info-slide">
                    Info about the 1st item
                </div>
                <div class="info-slide">
                    Info about the 2nd item
                </div>
                <div class="info-slide">
                    Info about the 3rd item
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- bottom images -->
            <div id="bottom-images">
                <img src="bottom-image-1.jpg">
                <img src="bottom-image-2.jpg">
                <img src="bottom-image-3.jpg">
            </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is when the user clicks on item 1:

a) it animates the div inside li by adding w-full class and removing w-full from all other _li_s

b) it uses the index of the clicked li to target the right info-slide class and animates it to show while hiding others

c) it targets bottom images and changes them.

I have started with something like this:

```
window.infoSlider = function () {
    return {
        selected: false,
        toggle(e) {
            const li = e.target.parentElement;
            const ul = li.parentElement;
            const index = [...ul.children].indexOf(li);
            console.log(index);
        }
    };
};
```

As you can see, I have managed to get the index of the li clicked, but I am lost on how to target the div inside the clicked li and animate by adding w-full class.

I also want to target the right info-slide div to make it appear and hide others.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In non-jQuery world we try to avoid manipulating the DOM directly. Instead of that we define state variables that will be the single source of truth of our frontend code. If we change a state variable Alpine.js will detect it and will change the DOM accordingly. In your example you want to define e.g. a `slide` variable. On a click event you want to mutate its value to the selected slide number. And any other place where something has to happen based on the slide number you use this `slide` state variable.

I modified you example:

```
<div id="slider" x-data="infoSlider">
  <!-- main image -->
  <div id="left-div">
    <ul>
      <li @click="toggle(1)">
        Item 1
        <div :class="slide == 1 ? 'w-full' : ''"></div>
      </li>
      <li @click="toggle(2)">
        Item 2
        <div :class="slide == 2 ? 'w-full' : ''"></div>
      </li>
      <li @click="toggle(3)">
        Item 3
        <div :class="slide == 3 ? 'w-full' : ''"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- info -->
  <div id="right-div">
    <div class="info-slides w-3/5 mx-auto mt-20">
      <div :class="slide == 1 ? 'info-slide' : ''">
          Info about the 1st item
      </div>
      <div :class="slide == 2 ? 'info-slide' : ''">
          Info about the 2nd item
      </div>
      <div :class="slide == 3 ? 'info-slide' : ''">
          Info about the 3rd item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- bottom images -->
  <div id="bottom-images" >
    <img x-show="slide != null" :src="`bottom-image-${slide}.jpg`">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('infoSlider', () => ({
    slide: 1,

    toggle(slide_number) {
      this.slide = (this.slide == slide_number) ? null : slide_number
    },
  }))
})
</script>
```

First, we use the [Alpine.data()](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) to create our `infoSlider` component. It has a single variable `slide` that holds the actual slide number or `null` if none of them is selected. The `toggle()` method handles the slide changing logic it has been attached to the `@click` event in the `<li>` tag.

The CSS class changing logic is in the `<li>` elements: `:class="slide == 1 ? 'w-full' : ''"`. We just checking whether the selected slide is the current slide or not, and add/remove the given class. It is a simple ternary operator, but Alpine.js supports [other syntax](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#binding-classes) as well.

We use similar method at the right info-slides and at the bottom images as well. Furthermore at the bottom image we used the `x-show` attribute to hide the image if no slide has been selected. Otherwise we use the slide number in a template literal to create the corresponding filename in the `src` attribute.

My example does not cover the animation part of your question because you need to understand the basics first, after that you can use the same logic to apply the animating CSS classes based on the slide variable. Alpine.js also has the [`x-transition`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/transition) builtin directive that helps animating stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Dauros for taking the time to answer my query. I will definitely give it a try and report back.